# How to handle Bitbucket rate limit exceeding (1000 calls/hour) when installing packages from private repositories with Composer

Tags: php, git, composer-php, bitbucket

**Context:**
We are a relatively medium sized company, and we use Bitbucket to host a lot of private git repositories that are shared across different teams. Mainly, our repositories are Composer packages and each particular project has its own list of requirements that get installed using Composer. We use *auth.json* credentials file to authenticate Composer calls to our Bitbucket sources.

**Notice:** the *auth.json* file is shared among team's members. As some team members don't have full access to all repositories, the resource in the *auth.json* file does have full access; to make it simple, a beginner team member won't have full access to all of ours private repositories from its account, but will be able to install all project dependencies required using the *auth.json* file.

**Problem:**
We noticed that -when resolving a dependency- [This is my own explanation and analysis, correct me if I'm wrong] Composer does fetch all tags and branches of a specific package before choosing the correct one that matches the requirements, as shown below:

[image]

This might not sound problematic unless, multiple teams member try to update/install project's dependencies in a relatively small time interval and so, Composer hits Bitbucket API rate limit

[image]                                             [Source](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/api-request-limits/)

=> I came to this conclusion by debugging composer packages installation (by adding the verbose argument i.e -vv) and I found that, under the hood it does this Bitbucket API call:
[image]

**Questions:**

1. Is my analysis correct? If not thanks for rectifying it and clarifying to me how it does work under the hood.
2. What's the best way to handle this use-case scenario and to not hit Bitbucket API rate limit? How could we make composer very specific, this might not be the best word but I hope that you get the idea.

Might be a more simple problem exposure: We are specifying a specific version of a package but composer fetches all version and then chooses the correct one:
we're declaring our dependencies as:

`"require": { "vendor/package": "version" }`

and to be more concrete, for the particular example attached we are just requiring version *1.1.1* not all other tags:

`"require": { "vendor/package": "1.1.1" }`

I'm interested more in an explanation to understand how does this work than only getting a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Composer Central/Shared Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318098/php-composer-central-shared-caching)